# Play Store is missing apps after restored from backup (EVO 4G)

Tags: applications, google-play-store, backup, factory-reset

I've seen some similar issues, but nothing quite the same as what I am having. Hopefully that means it is easy to fix.

So, I recently backed up all my apps to my sd card using MyBackup and then performed a factory reset. Afterwards, I reloaded all my apps back and everything went fine.

The problem is that now, in the "my apps" section of the market, it doesn't show anything except for my purchased apps, even though I have all my apps currently downloaded and installed on my phone.

Is there anyway I can update the market to reflect what is already installed on my phone??? I've already tried multiple times wiping the cache for the market and reseting, all to no avail.

Any help on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your backup program may not save the market links and the other info regarding how your app was acquired. As I'm not familiar with MyBackup I can't tell you thats it for sure. I use Titanium Backup which backs up the market info if you so select the option to back it up.

Comment: So is there anyway to backup/restore market links without being rooted?  From what I can tell, its not looking likely...

Answer (score 1):

Download [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en), press `Menu -> Market Tools -> Market Doctor`. This will attempt to repair the links between your installed apps and the Play Store. It may take a few times, I ran it several times once, and it got different apps fixed each time, but I eventually got all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All`, find the Market, click **Force Close** then **Clear Data**, and reboot the phone.  I've needed to do this a few times before TB had the option mbobino mentions.